# Mosquitto 2.0.14 MQTT with TLS1.2 connection issues Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet

Tags: mqtt, tls1.2, ubuntu-20.04, mosquitto

Mosquitto 2.0.14 Ubuntu 20.04 i9-12900, TLS1.2 connection issues
This all works perfectly until I try to secure it. I have added the details below, of how I created the certificates, logs, config file and how I am trying to connect.  If anyone could point me in the correct direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out mosquitto.key 2048
openssl req -new -key mosquitto.key -out mosquitto.csr
openssl x509 -req -in mosquitto.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out mosquitto.crt -days 3650 -sha256
openssl x509 -in ca.crt -out ca.pem //not sure this step was needed
```

/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

```
1643315161: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1643315161: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1643315161: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1643315161: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1643315161: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1643315161: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
1643315168: New connection from 192.168.1.99:46526 on port 8883.
1643315168: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
1643315228: New connection from 192.168.1.99:46558 on port 8883.
1643315228: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packet.
```

/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

```
per_listener_settings true
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.pem
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosquitto.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosquitto.crt
tls_version tlsv1.2

#default port
listener 8883 192.168.1.99
require_certificate true
allow_anonymous true
protocol mqtt
connection_messages true
log_type debug
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
```

Trying to add subscribe like this

```
mosquitto_sub -V mqttv311 -h 192.168.1.99 -p 8883 --cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.pem -t sensors/drone01/altitude -d
```

- Edit one

I created a client certificate:

```
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 90
```

To subscribe:

```
mosquitto_sub -V mqttv311 -h 192.168.1.99 -p 8883 --cert ./client.crt --key ./client.key -t sensors/drone01/altitude -d
```

Same message in the log file:
`1643322374: New connection from 192.168.1.99:49000 on port 8883. 1643322374: Client <unknown> disconnected due to malformed packe`t.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here - encrypt communications between the client and broker, or, that AND use a client certificate for authentication?. The `require_certificate true` setting in `mosquitto.conf` means clients need to provide a certificate for authentication and you are not doing that (`[--cert file] [--key file]` args to `mosquitto_sub`).

Comment: Please don't include code in the comments - edit your question (it gets very difficult to follow in the comments). I'd suggest starting getting TLS without client certificates working first (change one thing at a time). Move the `certfile`, `keyfile` etc below `listener` in `mosquitto.conf`. It's also likely you will also need the `--insecure` `mosquitto_sub` option with `mosquitto_sub` (as you are using IP addresses).

Comment: you must ALWAYS supply a `--capath` or `--cafile` to enable a TLS connection from the `mosquitto_sub` command. Just adding `--cert` and `--key` will not work

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting I have edited the question and removed the badly formatted comment.  What I am trying to do is secure the comms between the broker and the client  See Edit One for new information

Comment: Should the client certificate be signed with the server ca or should that be separately created?

Comment: They don't have to be the same, but if you are just playing then there is no reason not to reuse the same CA for everything. But if you just want secure comms, then there is no need for a client cert at all.

Comment: @hardillb what would the changes in the mosquitto.conf and the mosquitto_sub  command to configure it as you suggested with out client certs?

Comment: @DamienCooke it's 1am in the UK so hardillb may be a while. I figured I'd post an answer with the info you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic setup to get you started. I created the certificates in the same way you did (I usually use [certstrap](https://github.com/square/certstrap) for this due to its ease of use):

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out mosquitto.key 2048
openssl req -new -key mosquitto.key -out mosquitto.csr
openssl x509 -req -in mosquitto.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out mosquitto.crt -days 3650 -sha256
```

When generating `mosquitto.csr` I gave it the CN (Common Name) `127.0.0.1`. Basic `mosquitto.conf`:

```
log_type all

# Don't do the below in production (it allows anyone to connect with no auth)
allow_anonymous true

listener 8883
keyfile /path/mosquitto.key
certfile /path/mosquitto.crt
```

After starting mosquitto (I did this in the console using `mosquitto -c ./mosquitto.conf`) I then ran:

```
mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8883 --cafile ./ca.crt -t sensors/drone01/altitude -d
```

This successfully connected:

```
Client null sending CONNECT
Client null received CONNACK (0)
Client null sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: sensors/drone01/altitude, QoS: 0, Options: 0x00)
Client null received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
```

This does not use client certificates for authentication but it does check that the server name matches the CN in the certificate (try changing `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`). If your cert does not have the correct CN you would need the `--insecure` option).

Now that TLS is working lets add the requirement for the client certificate. Technically I could use the same certificate as above but that could be confusing so I'll generate a new one (in production I would use a different CA for this):

```
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 3650 -sha256
```

Now we update the `mosquitto.conf`:

```
log_type all

listener 8883
keyfile /path/mosquitto.key
certfile /path/mosquitto.crt

# We want to require a client certificate
require_certificate true

# This CA is used to verify the client certificate (it need not be the one used for the above mosquitto.crt)
cafile /path/ca.crt

# As we are passing a certificate we can choose to use the certificate CN as out username (removing need for allow_anonymous)
use_identity_as_username true
```

If you try connecting using the `mosquitto_sub` parameters used above it should now fail but the following works (or did when I tested it):

```
mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8883 --cafile ./ca.crt --cert ./client.crt --key ./client.key -t sensors/drone01/altitude -d
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I tried to connect with a WebSockets connection but had configured a mqtt protocol.

I switched to WebSockets by setting the protocol parameter in *mosquitto.conf*

```
protocol websockets
```